# level order traversal of binary tree c++

Tags: c++, algorithm, binary-tree, traversal

Hi I read this logic over internet and tried implementing the level order tree traversal in c++

```
void levelorder(struct node* root)
{
    struct node* temp = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    std::queue<node*> qq;

    if(root==NULL)
    {
        return;
    }
    qq.push(root);

    while(!qq.empty())
    {
        temp=qq.front();
        qq.pop();
        printf("%d",temp->data);
        qq.push(temp->left);
        qq.push(temp->right);
    }
}
```

But the above is giving me an error segmentation fault which I think is happening because

```
temp->left
```

does not exist. Or should i need llQueue for this implementation.Anybody has any idea about this ?

Comment: Don't call `malloc` for `temp` - if you assign one pointer to another, you didn't need to assign memory for the other pointer - it will be pointing to the same memory as the assigned pointer. You also shouldn't cast the return value of `malloc` - it's unnecessary.

Answer (score 3):

Ths posted code does not take into account the null pointers at the leaves of the tree. It can be fixed along these lines:

```
void levelorder(struct node* root)
{
    std::queue<node*> qq;
    qq.push(root);
    while(!qq.empty())
    {
        struct node* node = qq.front();
        qq.pop();
        if (node) {
            printf("%d",temp->data);
            qq.push(temp->left);
            qq.push(temp->right);
        }
    }
}
```

On the other hand, the memory allocation to temp is lost: This space is not freed and, moreover, will leak, as temp is assigned to somethig else.

Answer (score 2):

Two problems:

1. the memory allocated for temp is leaked and non-necessary
2. null pointer at leaf nodes not checked

The implementation proposed by @anumi is correct. But I'd prefer this:

```
void levelorder(struct node* root)
{
    if(!root) return;
    std::queue<node*> qq;
    qq.push(root);
    while(!qq.empty())
    {
        struct node* node = qq.front();
        qq.pop();
        printf("%d", node->data);
        if(node->left) qq.push(node->left);
        if(node->right) qq.push(node->right);
    }
}
```

Edit: handle empty tree according to comments.

Comment: +1, it's faster than useless recursive calls. BUT if tree is empty it fails too.

Comment: P.S. just add if( node == NULL ) return; in beginning, it's enough

Answer (score 0):

Your idea seems correct, however this is impossible to tell without knowing the actual data. In your code, it might be possible that the `left` and `right` members are `NULL` or point to undefined locations, which means that following the `left` or `right` pointers might result in errors.